# Is there a way to identify the instruction that caused the most recent Last Level Cache miss on modern Intel processors?

Tags: linux, performance, caching, intel, msr

I am currently able to read hardware counters on the Last Level Cache misses and references from user space using `wrmsr` to select them and then `rdpmc` to read them.

However, while some of the misses are very obvious references that I would not to hit the cache, others are much more subtle and sometimes move around when the same code path is executed multiple times (order 100,000 times).

I suspect that some of those misses are due to hardware prefetching, so I disabled the hardware prefetcher through BIOS, but I am still getting sliding cache misses with causes which are difficult to pin down.

**Is there some capability in either the Linux kernel or Intel's registers to determine the address of the instruction which caused the most recent Last Level cache miss?**

If it is useful, I am running `2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64` on `Intel Xeon X3470`.

Comment: You won't gain any significant information from a single miss, it doesn't even have to be related to your code. Have you tried running VTune or any other profiling tool to figure out if these misses come in phases? Alternatively you can run cachegrind or other cache simulation / profiling tools and see if they reproduce the problem

Comment: Actually for my particular application I have good reason to believe that I will gain information from a single miss. My entire code path runs in 1.5 us and I can count exactly 10 cache misses 99.9% of the time. I'm trying to understand exactly where they come from. Furthermore I think the question of whether I'll gain information is orthogonal to the question itself which is about capability and not utility

Comment: Well, regarding capability - i've heard of some instruction tracing features that are supposed to be available in the future, but your CPU is a little too old for that so I think your best bet is to simulate the cache behavior. If you need more help, I suggest you put some code sample or at least describe how your dataset is accessed.